# Django Tutorial: URL not mapping properly

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am at this stage of the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/

I have followed all the steps from creating the urls.py in my polls app directory, as well as making the edit to the urls.py in mysite directory. This is my code:

```
#polls\urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, urls
from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns(' ',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

and

```
#mysite\urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And this is what ends up happening when I try and load `http://localhost:8000/polls/` on my browser, this is the error I get:

```
ImportError at /polls/
cannot import name urls
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name urls
Exception Location: C:\Users\Paul.Zovighian\desktop\django\mysite\polls\urls.py in <module>, line 1
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Paul.Zovighian\\desktop\\django\\mysite',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.7-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Fri, 28 Nov 2014 16:29:44 +0000
```

Any ideas guys and gals??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to `import urls`.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, urls
```

Change it to.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
```

In your `polls\urls.py` module.

Comment: @ploo I'm glad that I could help.